# How to avoid paging in reports: create a report without page breaks?

Tags: ms-access, report

I have a long table in Microsoft Access and the report generated from this table has multiple pages.

How do I tell Access to generate a ONE page report, meaning: do not insert page breaks, just give me everything in one page. This is because I want to do my own paging later depending on my output format. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: An Access report *is* an output format.  I think you need to let us know what other output formats you are considering.  An Access report is almost never a good intermediate format.  The only exception I can think of is if you are using a "PDF printer" (like PDFCreator) to generate PDFs.  Of course, the same paging issues would apply to PDFs.

Comment: You could set the page height to 22" (the max for reports, if I'm not mistaken), but that's just a kludge. As @mwolfe02 says, why are you using a report for an intermediate purpose, instead of for what it's intended?

Comment: Like [Albert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614361/microsoft-access-how-to-avoid-paging-in-reports-create-a-report-without-page-br/6633695#6633695) mentions to export the data, you can always right click on the print preview of a report and export it to several formats. Some of them eliminate page breaks, like text file or excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to do your own paging, then obviously things just like word warp and text size and fonts used are going to have a SIGNIFICANT impact on this whole task as to when pages will break.

What you're proposing will rapidly become an extremely complex software development project. Font size and calculations can be quite a challenge.

I have to actually think what you're really looking for is some type of text export of the data in column format.  This suggests in place of using a report, you should be exporting your data as a text file format, either tab or csv (comma) delimited from the particular query in question.  You can also use XML exports.

If some types of totals and breaks need to be generated, it's not too usually hard to build that in the SQL or in fact write some code that generates the total data. Often for this I written with little effort some code to pre-process the data out to a temp table. You THEN use the built in text export commands. You want to use the built in export commands as they thus save you having to write such a text file export system.

This column data can then be consumed by your other program in which you're going to have to write will the correct paging and breaks in data and even perhaps things like page numbering etc. for your purposes.

So I don't think a report is the correct tool choice here. Using query along with code is quite easy. You can THEN use the built in text export commands that will produce tab delimited, comma delimited or even xml formats.

So you want to utilize the built and export features and I suspect that a report is not what you need, but a export of data of which can be processed by your own program for the page breaks etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Footer and Header in Design View!

Comment: In print preview, you still get pages. You must have looked at it in Report View.